# CNN with Sparse Input Does NOT Converge

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, sparse-matrix, convergence

I am practicing supervised classify problem with CNN network

The simple NN structure is: 5(Height) * 72(Width) input --> 5 * 4 kernel --> 1 * 2 pool --> Relu ==> 1 * 3 kernel --> Relu ==> fc --> 42 output ==> softmax ==> 1 max output

Adam optimizer, learning_rate = 0.001.

The original input is rather sparse, the ratio of (pixel value == 0) > 2/3.

Following some instruction, I tried to overfit the NN with small dataset.

The NN worked well with 256 samples (accuracy = 0.95), while failed to converge with 1024 samples. In 1024-sample case, the 2nd Convolution-layer generated all-zero output.

I've also tried (3 * 3) kernels, which generated similar result.

What should I do next to detect the problem? Did the problem rooted in sparse input that CNN is bad with?

Thank you very much!

Comment: how do you `pad` your conv/pooling layers? what is the range of values for the non-zero entries in your input? how are the labels distributed in your training set?

Comment: try adding batchnorm layers

Comment: @Shai. No padding. Input value range is [0, 1].